Widget test a screen that has a QRCode Scanner in Flutter
I'm using the plugin qr_code_scanner to read QRcode in my app. I have a widget (as below) in my AuthScreen and the reading of the qrcode triggers my Auth Flow.
The problem is that I need to test this screen and I cannot figure out a way to mimic or dispatch the qrcode scanner widget behaviour.. I was able to pump the AuthScreen correctly and it is fine with the qrcode scanner widget but from that I cannot find a way to trigger the reading..
Should I refactor the QrcodeScannerWidget and try to use a Stream through some service that the AuthScreen would also be aware?
Any help will be very much appreciated
here's my QrcodeScannerWidget code:
class QrcodeScannerWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  final void Function({String? code}) onCodeScanned;
  final String labelText;
  final String qrGlobalKey;
  final double viewSize;

  const QrcodeScannerWidget({
    super.key,
    this.labelText = '',
    this.qrGlobalKey = 'QR',
    this.viewSize = 100.0,
    required this.onCodeScanned,
  });

  @override
  State<QrcodeScannerWidget> createState() => _QrcodeScannerWidgetState();
}

class _QrcodeScannerWidgetState extends State<QrcodeScannerWidget> {
  static const spacer = AppGlobalMetrics.baseSpacer;

  late GlobalKey _qrKey;
  QRViewController? _scanController;
  late CameraFacing _cameraFacing;

  @override
  void reassemble() {
    if (mounted) {
      if (Platform.isAndroid) {
        _scanController?.pauseCamera();
      }
      _scanController?.resumeCamera();
    }
    super.reassemble();
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    _qrKey = GlobalKey(debugLabel: widget.qrGlobalKey);
    _cameraFacing = CameraFacing.front;
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    if (mounted) {
      if (Platform.isIOS) {
        _scanController?.pauseCamera();
      }
      _scanController?.dispose();
    }
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      color: Colors.transparent,
      child: _buildQrView(context),
    );
  }

  Widget _buildQrView(BuildContext context) {
    final viewSize = widget.viewSize;
    final cutOutSize = viewSize - 40;
    return Card(
      clipBehavior: Clip.antiAlias,
      elevation: 4.0,
      shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0)),
      margin: const EdgeInsets.all(spacer),
      child: SizedBox(
        width: viewSize,
        height: viewSize,
        child: QRView(
          key: _qrKey,
          onQRViewCreated: _onQRViewCreated,
          cameraFacing: _cameraFacing,
          overlay: QrScannerOverlayShape(
            borderColor: Colors.red,
            borderRadius: 10,
            borderLength: 30,
            borderWidth: 10,
            cutOutSize: cutOutSize,
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  void _onQRViewCreated(QRViewController controller) {
    setState(() {
      _scanController = controller;
    });
    _scanController?.scannedDataStream.listen((Barcode? barcode) async {
      if (barcode != null) {
        await _scanController?.pauseCamera();
        _onCodeScanned(barcode);
      }
    });
  }

  Future<void> _onCodeScanned(Barcode barcode) async {
    _scanController?.dispose();
    widget.onCodeScanned(code: barcode.code);
  }
}

here's my AuthScreen code:
class AuthScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  static const routeName = '/auth';
  const AuthScreen({
    super.key,
    required this.appInfoService,
    required this.connService,
  });

  final AppInfoService appInfoService;
  final ConnectivityService connService;

  @override
  State<AuthScreen> createState() => _AuthScreenState();
}

class _AuthScreenState extends State<AuthScreen> {
  static const spacer = AppGlobalMetrics.baseSpacer;

  String _errorMessage = '';
  bool _isPending = false;

  bool _showBottomNavBar = false;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Column(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
        children: [
          AppTopBarWidget(
            connService: widget.connService,
            showAppInfoButton: true,
          ),
          Expanded(
            child: LayoutBuilder(builder: (_, constraints) {
              return Container(
                child: _buildContent(constraints),
              );
            }),
          ),
          if (_showBottomNavBar)
            NavBottomBarWidget(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: spacer),
              children: [
                Expanded(
                  child: MainButtonWidget(
                    onPressed: _reloadReadingUI,
                    label: 'TENTAR NOVAMENTE',
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          AppBottomBarWidget(
            appInfoService: widget.appInfoService,
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget _buildContent(BoxConstraints constraints) {
    final wWidth = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
    MainAxisAlignment mainAxisAlignment = MainAxisAlignment.center;

    List<Widget> children = [];

    if (_isPending) {
      children = [
        const PendingActionWidget(
          topIcon: Icons.lock_person,
        ),
      ];
    } else if (_errorMessage.isNotEmpty) {
      children = [
        ErrorActionWidget(
          error: _errorMessage,
        )
      ];
    } else {
      mainAxisAlignment = MainAxisAlignment.end;
      children = [
        const ReadingActionWidget(topIcon: Icons.lock_person),
        SizedBox(
          width: wWidth * 0.4,
          child: QrcodeScannerWidget(
            onCodeScanned: _onCodeScanned,
            viewSize: wWidth * 0.4,
          ),
        ),
      ];
    }

    return SingleChildScrollView(
      child: Container(
        constraints: BoxConstraints(
          minHeight: constraints.maxHeight,
        ),
        child: Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
          mainAxisAlignment: mainAxisAlignment,
          children: children,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  void _onCodeScanned({String? code}) {
    log(code ?? '');
    if (code == null) {
      setState(() {
        _errorMessage =
            'Não foi possível fazer a leitura do QRCode pois o código voltou sem dados.';
      });
      return;
    }
    _authenticateCrewMember(code);
  }

  Future<void> _authenticateCrewMember(String code) async {
    try {
      setState(() {
        _isPending = true;
        _showBottomNavBar = false;
      });
      await Provider.of<AuthProvider>(context, listen: false)
          .authenticateCrewMember(qrCodePayload: code);
      if (mounted) {
        Navigator.of(context).pushReplacementNamed(MenuScreen.routeName,
            arguments: {'backButton': false});
      }
    } catch (e) {
      setState(() {
        _errorMessage = '$e';
        _isPending = false;
        _showBottomNavBar = true;
      });
    }
  }

  void _reloadReadingUI() {
    setState(() {
      _errorMessage = '';
      _showBottomNavBar = false;
    });
  }
}

Here is my test (it passes) so far:
Future<void> _createWidget(
  WidgetTester tester,
  AppInfoService appInfoService,
  ConnectivityService connService,
  AuthProvider mockAuthProvider,
) async {
  await tester.pumpWidget(MultiProvider(
    providers: [
      ChangeNotifierProvider<AuthProvider>(
        create: (ctx) => mockAuthProvider,
      ),
    ],
    child: MaterialApp(
      home: AuthScreen(
        appInfoService: appInfoService,
        connService: connService,
      ),
    ),
  ));
  await tester.pump();
}

Future<void> main() async {

  late AppInfoService appInfoService;
  late ConnectivityService connService;

  late AuthProvider mockAuthProvider;

  setUp(() async {
    appInfoService = MockAppInfoService();
    appInfoService.initialize();
    connService = MockConnService();
    connService.initialize();

    mockAuthProvider = MockAuthProvider();
  });

  tearDown(() {
    connService.dispose();
  });
  group('AuthScreen -', () {
    testWidgets('should load properly on boot', (WidgetTester tester) async {
      await _createWidget(
        tester,
        appInfoService,
        connService,
        mockAuthProvider,
      );
      Finder qrcodeScannerWidget = find.byType(QrcodeScannerWidget);
      Finder readingWidget = find.byType(ReadingActionWidget);
      Finder pendingWidget = find.byType(PendingActionWidget);
      Finder errorWidget = find.byType(ErrorActionWidget);

      expect(qrcodeScannerWidget, findsOneWidget);
      expect(readingWidget, findsOneWidget);

      expect(pendingWidget, findsNothing);
      expect(errorWidget, findsNothing);
    });
  });
}


here's my flutter doctor output:
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.16.0, on macOS 13.2.1 22D68 darwin-arm64, locale en-BR)
    • Flutter version 3.16.0 on channel stable at /Users/tattivitorino/fvm/versions/3.16.0
    • Upstream repository https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
    • Framework revision db7ef5bf9f (5 months ago), 2023-11-15 11:25:44 -0800
    • Engine revision 74d16627b9
    • Dart version 3.2.0
    • DevTools version 2.28.2

and the qr_code_scanner plugin:
qr_code_scanner: ^1.0.1


To test the actual reading will require an integration test but you can still widget test the flow by calling the qrcodeScannerWidget.onCodeScanned() function and verifying that your auth flow is triggered.
